# Stop a thread if function delays the response

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have the following loop which is calling the getHLS function in a separate thread for each of the text lines. The problem is that the getHLS function might be really slow at some times, and I am looking for a way to "timeout" a thread if the function does not return anything for 10 seconds.

```
links = open("links.txt")
lines = links.readlines()

linenumber = 0
for line in lines:
    linenumber += 1
    thread = threading.Thread(target = getHLS, args = (line, linenumber))
    thread.setDaemon(False)
    thread.start()
    if threading.active_count() == 50:
        thread.join(10)
```

Comment: Several issues here. Any timeout due to slow operation should be handled within *getHLS*. *thread.setDaemon(False)* is redundant because that's the default. Not sure what you're trying to achieve by checking is there are exactly 50 threads running. It's quite possible that that condition will never be met. Even if it is, you then wait (join) on the most recent thread with a timeout of 10 seconds. If the join does time out, you don't do anything about it